# AVAssetWriter change of quality on the fly

Tags: iphone, avassetwriter

Hey I am currently working with the AVAssetWriter and the AVAssetWriterInput.

In my project I would like to use the hardware acceleration of the iPhone.
Is it possible to use the AVAssetWriter to create compressed images and change the quality on the fly? That means after I initialized the AVAssetWriterInput instance?

Comment: Unfortunately you can not do this. You would have to create a new AVAssetWriter with the new settings.

Comment: After some investigation in that direction I found out myself already. I am creating a new session now each time I like to change the compression rate. That does the trick ;)